C# float to int conversion problem (in Unity)
i'm having a little problem converting float to int in C# (Unity)
some how when i try
x * 1.05, it comes out x * 1
x * 1.1, it comes out x * 1.05
using System; 

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
     int gainAmount = 20;
     float _gainAmountModifier = 1.05f
      gainAmount = (int)(gainAmount * _gainAmountModifier);
     Debug.Log(_gainAmountModifier);
     Debug.Log(gainAmount); 
   }
}
// The example displays output like the following:
//       1.05
//       20

when i test this in a C# sandbox
using System; 

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
    int var_int = 100;
    float var_f = var_int;
    var_f = var_f * 1.05f; 
    var_int = (int)var_f;

    Console.WriteLine(var_f);
    Console.Write(var_int);
   }
}
// The example displays output like the following:
//       105
//       104

so it seems like its rounding down 1?

Basically 1.05f is exactly 1.0499999523162841796875, so your value is just less than 105, and the cast rounds it down. If you want precise decimal representations, use decimal instead of float.

@JonSkeet or instead of casting (int) which always simply cuts of the decimals simply use Mathf.RoundToInt which would result in 105 as well without using heavier data types

@derHugo: Potentially. It depends what the OP is actually most interested in. That's why I said "if you want precise decimal representations".

Floating point numbers are not exact!
1.05 can as well be 1.049999999 or 1.050000001 (or similar).
In this exact case e.g. 1.0499999523162841796875.
Instead of casting (int) which always simply cuts of the decimals simply use Mathf.RoundToInt which would result in 105 as well without the need for heavier data types (like double or decimal)

"Floating point numbers are not exact!" Yes they are. It's just that the value represented by a decimal literal isn't always exactly representable in a binary floating point value. The value of 1.05f is exactly 1.0499999523162841796875. It's definitely not 1.050000001, for example. (Note that decimal is a floating point type as well... would you say decimal isn't exact?)

OP writes 1.05f and expects the value to be exactly that. This when I say floating point numbers are not exact I think we both and hopefully OP know pretty much what I mean by that. The values I gave are examples to understand a principle, not the exact values .. OP doesn't really care about the exact representation value. I answered the question to "I have a problem converting float to int"  .. and I would say decimal is definitely way more exact .. but depending on use cases even that migjt not be enough ^^ especially in those endless incremental games you might need BigDouble instead

If your decimal is (again I didn't bother to look up exact values but let's assume) 1.04999999999999999999999999999999999... .. then it would still yield 104 unexpectedly if you simply cast to int instead of rounding

"This when I say floating point numbers are not exact I think we both and hopefully OP know pretty much what I mean by that" - I wouldn't be so sure about that. There's a big difference between saying "the conversion from a decimal representation to a binary floating point can lose information" and "floating point numbers themselves are inherently inexact". (Basically, I believe that details matter, and I think it's more helpful to be precise in what's going on rather than propagating a commonly-repeated over-simplification.)

my question was "float to int conversion problem", while its good to know the reason, you didnt really provide a solution to the problem. saying "Note that decimal is a floating point type as well... would you say decimal isn't exact?" is not very helpful. thanks
